# Find a word and increment the number in the word & save into new files

Tags: awk, sed, numbers, increment

I am looking for a perl/awk/sed command to auto-increment the numbers line in file, P1.tcl:

```
run_build_model sparc_ifu_dec
run_drc
set_faults -model path_delay -atpg_effectiveness -fault_coverage
add_delay_paths P1
set_atpg -abort_limit 1000
run_atpg -ndetects 1000
```

I would like to change P1 from P2 to P500 and save into new files such as P2.tcl,P3.tcl.... P500.tcl

I searched this on the web, but found only way to replace/generate one file. such as P2.tcl

Best,

Jaeyoung

Comment: use a var and loop

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
for i in {2..500}; do
    cp P1.tcl P$i.tcl
    sed -i s/P1/P$i/ P$i.tcl
done
```

Comment: Note that range brace expansion is supported  by Bash 3+ and ksh, not all shells.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is less clear but faster for such long loops:

```
awk '{for (n=2; n<=500; n++) {line = gensub(/P1/, "P" n, "g", $0); print line > "P" n ".tcl"}}' P1.tcl
```

using `gensub` to replace `P1` by `"P" n`.